# Using CSS { white-space: nowrap } with Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I currently have a report with lots of wide columns that I am emailing directly out of SQL.  I am generating the HTML for it dynamically but have come across an issue with column widths.

I have inserted the following CSS:

```
#tableMain 
TH { 
    text-align: center; 
    white-space: pre; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    padding: 0; 
    border-spacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    background-color: #f0f0f0; 
    font: 11pt bold arial sans-serif; 
}
```

Now while the html generated this renders fine in IE, it insists on wrapping the cell contents onto two rows in Outlook.

In Internet explorer:
[image: As displayed in IE]

In Outlook
[image: As displayed in Outlook]

Outlook is our company wide email client so I don't need to support multiple clients, but I do need it to work nicely here.

And suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: I don't have Outlook here to test, but Outlook and CSS is always an iffy subject. Now your code has a different value for `white-space` than your question title, so the question rises, did you test both those values? Did you test other values too? What you can try as experiments: put the `nowrap` attribute in each of the table cells, give them a `width` or a `min-width`. Also, can you say which version(s) of Outlook you need to support?

Comment: Hi Lister. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I can't enforce minimum widths directly, as the column list is being generated dynamically. I basically have a stored proc that I pass a temp table to and some other info and it generates an email for me with the table inserted. I'll post the full code I'm using later, have been pulled off onto another project - priorities shifted as usual - it's a dev's life!

Answer (score 3):

The question is quite old, but unfortunately still relevant.
The simplest solution is to replace all whitespaces with `&nbsp;`.
But be carfull with line lengths.

Answer (score 1):

That fact is that Outlook uses Word (not IE) for rendering HTML markup of emails. All supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties you may find described in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I'll have a look at this.  I think I'm hitting a maximum screen width as things display nicely if I have fewer columns.  I'll have a look over the links you've posted later, I've been pulled onto a different project short term. Cheers.

Comment: With an appreciation for the rtfm answer, only the first link has documentation about nowrap.  And, I have found Outlook does not respect the td attribute or the div attribute, despite being listed there.  So, this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I also had that problem and it seems that there is something like maximum width of an email in Outlook and it's around 2200px(at least versions 2007-13). I guess one way to send the whole table without wrapping would be opening the dynamically generated HTML table in headless browser like PhantomJS, and use the Javascript to split table into smaller ones based on column widths, but I think this solution woluld be rather inefficient.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Michelem I fail to see how this answer is supposed to be a comment. It's a perfectly good answer with a little esoteric idea of solving the issue.